# Please explain the exec() function and its family

Tags: c, unix, execl

What is the `exec()` function and its family?  Why is this function used and how does its work?

Please anyone explain these functions.

Comment: Try to read Stevens again, & clarify what it is you don't understand.

Comment: That's [Advanced Programing in the Unix Environment](https://www.amazon.com/Advanced-Programming-UNIX-Environment-3rd/dp/0321637739) by Stevens et al. (he died so a coauthor took over). This is a 1000+ page tome, so somewhat overkill for this specific question, but well worth the time and money.

Answer (score 278):

Simplistically, in UNIX, you have the concept of processes and programs. A process is an environment in which a program executes.

The simple idea behind the UNIX "execution model" is that there are two operations you can do.

The first is to [`fork()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html), which creates a brand new process containing a duplicate (mostly) of the current program, including its state. There are a few differences between the two processes which allow them to figure out which is the parent and which is the child.

The second is to [`exec()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html), which replaces the program in the current process with a brand new program.

From those two simple operations, the entire UNIX execution model can be constructed.

---

To add some more detail to the above:

The use of `fork()` and `exec()` exemplifies the spirit of UNIX in that it provides a very simple way to start new processes.

The `fork()` call makes a near duplicate of the current process, identical in almost every way (not *everything* is copied over, for example, resource limits in some implementations, but the idea is to create as close a copy as possible). Only one process *calls* `fork()` but *two* processes return from that call - sounds bizarre but it's really quite elegant

The new process (called the child) gets a different process ID (PID) and has the PID of the old process (the parent) as its parent PID (PPID).

Because the two processes are now running exactly the same code, they need to be able to tell which is which - the return code of `fork()` provides this information - the child gets 0, the parent gets the PID of the child (if the `fork()` fails, no child is created and the parent gets an error code).

That way, the parent knows the PID of the child and can communicate with it, kill it, wait for it and so on (the child can always find its parent process with a call to `getppid()`).

The `exec()` call replaces the entire current contents of the process with a new program. It loads the program into the current process space and runs it from the entry point.

So, `fork()` and `exec()` are often used in sequence to get a new program running as a child of a current process. Shells typically do this whenever you try to run a program like `find` - the shell forks, then the child loads the `find` program into memory, setting up all command line arguments, standard I/O and so forth.

But they're not required to be used together. It's perfectly acceptable for a program to call `fork()` without a following `exec()` if, for example, the program contains both parent and child code (you need to be careful what you do, each implementation may have restrictions).

This was used quite a lot (and still is) for daemons which simply listen on a TCP port and fork a copy of themselves to process a specific request while the parent goes back to listening. For this situation, the program contains both the parent *and* the child code.

Similarly, programs that know they're finished and just want to run another program don't need to `fork()`, `exec()` and then `wait()/waitpid()` for the child. They can just load the child directly into their current process space with `exec()`.

Some UNIX implementations have an optimized `fork()` which uses what they call copy-on-write. This is a trick to delay the copying of the process space in `fork()` until the program attempts to change something in that space. This is useful for those programs using only `fork()` and not `exec()` in that they don't have to copy an entire process space. Under Linux, `fork()` only makes a copy of the page tables and a new task structure, `exec()` will do the grunt work of "separating" the memory of the two processes.

If the `exec` *is* called following `fork` (and this is what happens mostly), that causes a write to the process space and it is then copied for the child process, before modifications are allowed.

Linux also has a `vfork()`, even more optimised, which shares just about *everything* between the two processes. Because of that, there are certain restrictions in what the child can do, and the parent halts until the child calls `exec()` or `_exit()`.

The parent has to be stopped (and the child is not permitted to return from the current function) since the two processes even share the same stack. This is slightly more efficient for the classic use case of `fork()` followed immediately by `exec()`.

Note that there is a whole family of `exec` calls (`execl`, `execle`, `execve` and so on) but `exec` in context here means any of them.

The following diagram illustrates the typical `fork/exec` operation where the `bash` shell is used to list a directory with the `ls` command:

```
+--------+
| pid=7  |
| ppid=4 |
| bash   |
+--------+
    |
    | calls fork
    V
+--------+             +--------+
| pid=7  |    forks    | pid=22 |
| ppid=4 | ----------> | ppid=7 |
| bash   |             | bash   |
+--------+             +--------+
    |                      |
    | waits for pid 22     | calls exec to run ls
    |                      V
    |                  +--------+
    |                  | pid=22 |
    |                  | ppid=7 |
    |                  | ls     |
    V                  +--------+
+--------+                 |
| pid=7  |                 | exits
| ppid=4 | <---------------+
| bash   |
+--------+
    |
    | continues
    V
```

Comment: Thanks for the shell reference with the find program. Exactly what I needed to understand.

Comment: Why is `exec` the utility used for redirecting the current process's IO?  How did the "null" case, running exec without an argument, get used for this convention?

Comment: @Ray, I've always thought of it as a natural extension. If you think of `exec` as the means to replace the current program (the shell) in this process with another, then _not_ specifying that other program to replace it with can simply mean you _don't_ want to replace it.

Comment: I see what you mean if by "natural extension" you mean something along the lines of "organic growth".  It seems that redirecting would have been added on to support the program replacement function, and I can see this behavior remaining in the degenerate case of `exec` being called without a program.  But it's a bit odd in this scenario since the original usefulness of redirecting for a new program -- a program which would actually get `exec`uted -- disappears and you have a useful artifact, redirecting the current program -- which is not being `exec`uted or started up in any way -- instead.

Answer (score 47):

Functions in the exec() family have different behaviours:

- l : arguments are passed as a list of strings to the main()
- v : arguments are passed as an array of strings to the main()
- p : path/s to search for the new running program
- e : the environment can be specified by the caller

You can mix them, therefore you have:

- int execl(const char *path, const char *arg, ...);
- int execlp(const char *file, const char *arg, ...);
- int execle(const char *path, const char *arg, ..., char * const envp[]);
- int execv(const char *path, char *const argv[]);
- int execvp(const char *file, char *const argv[]);
- int execvpe(const char *file, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]);

For all of them the initial argument is the name of a file that is to be executed.

For more information read [exec(3) man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html):

```
man 3 exec  # if you are running a UNIX system
```

Comment: Interestingly, you missed [`execve()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execve.html) from your list, which is defined by POSIX, and you added `execvpe()`, which is not defined by POSIX (mostly for reasons of historical precedent; it completes the set of functions).  Otherwise, a helpful explanation of the naming convention for the family — a useful adjunct to [paxdiablo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14860/paxdiablo)'a [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4205020/15168) which explains more about the workings of the functions.

Comment: And, in your defense, I see that the Linux man page for `execvpe()` (et al) does not list `execve()`; it has its own, separate man page (at least on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) — the difference being that the other `exec()` family functions are listed in section 3 (functions) whereas `execve()` is listed in section 2 (system calls).  Basically, all the other functions in the family are implemented in terms of a call to `execve()`.

Answer (score 20):

The `exec` family of functions make your process execute a different program, replacing the old program it was running. I.e., if you call

```
execl("/bin/ls", "ls", NULL);
```

then the `ls` program is executed with the process id, current working dir and user/group (access rights) of the process that called `execl`. Afterwards, the original program is not running anymore.

To start a new process, the `fork` system call is used. To execute a program without replacing the original, you need to `fork`, then `exec`.

Comment: Thank you that was really helpful. I'm currently doing a project requiring us to use exec() and your description solidified my understanding.

Answer (score 8):

> what is the exec function and its family.

The `exec` function  family is all functions used to execute a file, such as `execl`, `execlp`, `execle`, `execv`, and `execvp`.They are all frontends for `execve` and provide different methods of calling it.

> why is this function used

Exec functions are used when you want to execute (launch) a file (program).

> and how does it work.

They work by overwriting the current process image with the one that you launched. They replace (by ending) the currently running process (the one that called the exec command) with the new process that has launched.

For more details: [see this link](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execv).

Answer (score 7):

`exec` is often used in conjunction with `fork`, which I saw that you also asked about, so I will discuss this with that in mind.

`exec` turns the current process into another program.  If you ever watched Doctor Who, then this is like when he regenerates -- his old body is replaced with a new body.

The way that this happens with your program and `exec` is that a lot of the resources that the OS kernel checks to see if the file you are passing to `exec` as the program argument (first argument) is executable by the current user (user id of the process making the `exec` call) and if so it replaces the virtual memory mapping of the current process with a virtual memory the new process and copies the `argv` and `envp` data that were passed in the `exec` call into an area of this new virtual memory map.  Several other things may also happen here, but the files that were open for the program that called `exec` will still be open for the new program and they will share the same process ID, but the program that called `exec` will cease (unless exec failed).

The reason that this is done this way is that by separating *running*  *a*  *new*  *program* into two steps like this you can do some things between the two steps.  The most common thing to do is to make sure that the new program has certain files opened as certain file descriptors.  (remember here that file descriptors are not the same as `FILE *`, but are `int` values that the kernel knows about).  Doing this you can:

```
int X = open("./output_file.txt", O_WRONLY);

pid_t fk = fork();
if (!fk) { /* in child */
    dup2(X, 1); /* fd 1 is standard output,
                   so this makes standard out refer to the same file as X  */
    close(X);

    /* I'm using execl here rather than exec because
       it's easier to type the arguments. */
    execl("/bin/echo", "/bin/echo", "hello world");
    _exit(127); /* should not get here */
} else if (fk == -1) {
    /* An error happened and you should do something about it. */
    perror("fork"); /* print an error message */
}
close(X); /* The parent doesn't need this anymore */
```

This accomplishes running:

```
/bin/echo "hello world" > ./output_file.txt
```

from the command shell.

Answer (score 5):

When a process uses fork(), it creates a duplicate copy of itself and this duplicates becomes the child of the process. The fork() is implemented using clone() system call in linux which returns twice from kernel.

- A non-zero value(Process ID of child) is returned to the parent.
- A value of zero is returned to the child.
- In case the child is not created successfully due to any issues like low memory, -1 is returned to the fork().

Let’s understand this with an example:

```
pid = fork(); 
// Both child and parent will now start execution from here.
if(pid < 0) {
    //child was not created successfully
    return 1;
}
else if(pid == 0) {
    // This is the child process
    // Child process code goes here
}
else {
    // Parent process code goes here
}
printf("This is code common to parent and child");
```

In the example, we have assumed that exec() is not used inside the child process.

But a parent and child differs in some of the PCB(process control block) attributes. These are:

1. PID - Both child and parent have a different Process ID.
2. Pending Signals - The child doesn’t inherit Parent’s pending signals. It will be empty for the child process when created.
3. Memory Locks - The child doesn’t inherit its parent’s memory locks. Memory locks are locks which can be used to lock a memory area and then this memory area cannot be swapped to disk.
4. Record Locks - The child doesn’t inherit its parent’s record locks. Record locks are associated with a file block or an entire file.
5. Process resource utilisation and CPU time consumed is set to zero for the child.
6. The child also doesn’t inherit timers from the parent.

**But what about the child memory? Is a new address space created for a child?**

The answers in no. After the fork(), both parent and child share the memory address space of parent. In linux, these address space are divided into multiple pages. Only when the child writes to one of the parent memory pages, a duplicate of that page is created for the child. This is also known as copy on write(Copy parent pages only when the child writes to it).

Let’s understand copy on write with an example.

```
int x = 2;
pid = fork();
if(pid == 0) {
    x = 10;
    // child is changing the value of x or writing to a page
    // One of the parent stack page will contain this local               variable. That page will be duplicated for child and it will store the value 10 in x in duplicated page.  
}
else {
    x = 4;
}
```

**But why is copy on write necessary?**

A typical process creation takes place through fork()-exec() combination. Let’s first understand what exec() does.

Exec() group of functions replaces the child’s address space with a new program. Once exec() is called within a child, a separate address space will be created for the child which is totally different from the parent’s one.

If there was no copy on write mechanism associated with fork(), duplicate pages would have created for the child and all the data would have been copied to child’s pages. Allocating new memory and copying data is a very expensive process(takes processor’s time and other system resources). We also know that in most cases, the child is going to call exec() and that would replace the child’s memory with a new program. So the first copy which we did would have been a waste if copy on write was not there.

```
pid = fork();
if(pid == 0) {
    execlp("/bin/ls","ls",NULL);
    printf("will this line be printed"); // Think about it
    // A new memory space will be created for the child and that   memory will contain the "/bin/ls" program(text section), it's stack, data section and heap section
else {
    wait(NULL);
    // parent is waiting for the child. Once child terminates, parent will get its exit status and can then continue
}
return 1; // Both child and parent will exit with status code 1.
```

**Why does parent waits for a child process?**

1. The parent can assign a task to it’s child and wait till it completes it’s task. Then it can carry some other work.
2. Once the child terminates, all the resources associated with child are freed except for the process control block. Now, the child is in zombie state. Using wait(), parent can inquire about the status of child and then ask the kernel to free the PCB. In case parent doesn’t uses wait, the child will remain in the zombie state.

**Why is exec() system call necessary?**

It’s not necessary to use exec() with fork(). If the code that the child will execute is within the program associated with parent, exec() is not needed.

But think of cases when the child has to run multiple programs. Let’s take the example of shell program. It supports multiple commands like find, mv, cp, date etc. Will be it right to include program code associated with these commands in one program or have child load these programs into the memory when required?

It all depends on your use case. You have a web server which given an input x that returns the 2^x to the clients. For each request, the web server creates a new child and asks it to compute. Will you write a separate program to calculate this and use exec()? Or you will just write computation code inside the parent program?

Usually, a process creation involves a combination of fork(), exec(), wait() and exit() calls.

Answer (score 4):

The `exec(3,3p)` functions *replace* the current process with another. That is, the current process *stops*, and another runs instead, taking over some of the resources the original program had.

Comment: Not quite.  It replaces the current process *image* with a new process image.  The process is the same process with the same pid, the same environment, and the same file descriptor table.  What has changed is the entire virtual memory and CPU state.

Comment: @JeremyP "The same file descriptor" was important here, it explains how redirection works in shells! I was puzzled on how redirection can work if exec overwrites everything! Thanks