# Why do the exec()-family functions actually return a value?

Tags: c, linux, unix, return, execl

In a book about Linux and Unix programming, I´ve found this statement (emphasize mine):

> "*All functions **(`exec()`-family)** return `-1` in the case of an error. Otherwise at successful execution there is no return back to the calling program. Thus, it is redundant to check the return value; you can directly continue with the error routine.*"

This seems to fit with the according Linux [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html):

> "*RETURN VALUE - The `exec()` functions return only if an error has occurred. The
>          return value is `-1`, and `errno` is set to indicate the error.*"

Thus, If the current process image was successfully replaced with a new process image, there should be no return. Only if there was happen an error at the creation of the new image, one of the `exec()`-functions actually returns (`-1`).

---

Means, in turn, instead of, f.e.:

```
if ( execl("/bin/foo", "foo", "bar", (char *) NULL) == -1 )
{
    perror("Execution of foo failed");
    // further error routine.
}
```

One can simply do:

```
execl("/bin/foo", "foo", "bar", (char *) NULL);

perror("Execution of foo failed");
// further error routine.
```

---

- But why do the functions of the `exec()`-family have a return value then in general, if the further program execution of the caller already indicates that an error has happen?
- Wouldn´t a simple `return;` statement at the end of the functions and a respective return type of `void` be sufficient?
- Is it just to fit the common method/practice to always checking return values or has it a different purpose?

---

Related:

- [Please explain the exec() function and its family](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204915/please-explain-the-exec-function-and-its-family/4205020#4205020)
- [why the exec() family of functions doesn't execute the code after exec()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899582/why-the-exec-family-of-functions-doesnt-execute-the-code-after-exec)
- [Working of exec family functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483956/working-of-exec-family-functions)

Comment: Consistency with other syscalls?

Comment: Yes, a return from an `exec*` function is a sufficient indication of an error. I suppose those functions return an `int` for historical reasons, since `int` used to be an implicit value type for old C functions and the void return type didn't exist for several years while C was already being used to implement UNIX.

Comment: @PSkocik That was even way before C89/C90. No need to adjust the functions to the standard? Or is this for compatibility with pre-standard C systems?

Comment: AFAIK, the first standards literally promised compatibility and codification of existing practices rather than design by committee. (The later standards have been breaking the latter promise more and more.)