# How does exec family of functions work internally?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, exec, elf, execv

Does **execv()** family of functions call **mmap()** functions internally to load text,data,bss segments from elf file? Can any one please share the blocks or steps involved in the working of **exec()** functions. Also please suggest some links or books to learn about how exec works internally.

Comment: No idea.  I would look at the source code as my next step.

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/3/execv

Comment: you can use strace on a program using execv to see all system calls

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Please explain the exec() function and its family](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4204915/608639)

Answer (score 4):

The **execv()** is a userspace libc wrapper which pass control through syscall to kernel side into [do_execve()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/exec.c#L1741) .

do_execve() finds appropriate [binary handler](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/exec.c#L1572) for exec file to load. We will next consider example for ELF executable format.

The appropriate binary handler for elf format is [load_elf_binary()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/binfmt_elf.c#L666) . It uses [elf_map()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/binfmt_elf.c#L336) to map appropriate elf segments to memory through vm_mmap() API.

Is that what are you asking about?

Comment: Yes, this is what I want, I can use this information to get a detailed overview. Thanks Alex