# printf after execl not showing

Tags: c

I'm testing the `execl()` function tho I'm not being able to solve how to make the `printf()` after the `execl()` show up when I run the program. I figured out it has something to do with the `fflush()` function, although I still can't do it. 
Heres the code.

```
#include<sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
    printf ("Show content from directory /:\n");
    execl( "/bin/ls", "ls", "-l", "/", NULL );
    fprintf (stdout,"End of command: ls -l /\n");
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

Comment: You never return from an `exec*()` call, except if it fails.

Comment: It won't show up unless `execl()` fails. The `exec()` family of functions literally completely replace the current process. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204915/please-explain-the-exec-function-and-its-family  (I'll let others decide if this is a duplicate of that question.)

Comment: Do you know what `execl()` does?  Do you know how very, very different it is from `system()`?  (You probably want `system()`.)

Comment: If you don't want to replace the current process, call `execl()` in a child process created with `fork()`. Then use `wait()` in the parent to wait for it to finish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the man page
https://linux.die.net/man/3/execl

**Return Value**
The exec() functions only return if an error has occurred. The return value is -1, and errno is set to indicate the error.

If you really want to use `execl()` instead of `system()`, then
you should change the code like this.

```
#include<sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    printf ("Show content from directory /:\n");

    pid_t p=fork(); // create a child process
    if(p==0) // if we are in the child process
    {
      execl( "/bin/ls", "ls", "-l", "/", NULL ); // replace it with a new program
      perror("execl"); // reaching this line is necessarily a failure
      exit(1); // terminate child process in any case
    }
    waitpid(p, NULL, 0); // wait for child process to terminate

    fprintf (stdout,"End of command: ls -l /\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    return 0;
}
```